# CSP Violation error for blocked URI https://searches8704500-a.akamaihd.net

Tags: security, content-security-policy, session-hijacking

I have added CSP in my application and from last few days my CSP-report is sending mail regarding violation rule where blocked uri - https://searches8704500-a.akamaihd.net. I am not sure what is this or is this any type malicious browser hijacking attack. Please help me what resolution should i implement to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you share the CSP header to get more clarification?

With my understanding on CSP if the URI that you have mentioned is not used in your project or from 3rd party plugins(if any) then there is something malicious happening. And I also see that "akamaihd.net" is some kind of a spam(google for it). If that's the case then your CSP is preventing the execution of the spam URI, you need to dig deep into your project to identify which part is triggering this URI. You can use the network option from the debugging menu to look into the URI requests from your web page and can narrow down the root cause. Hope this helps.